# How to search word in array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

How do I find in all elements in the array `myArray` containing the word "**wish**" in its `title`. For that I want to use **Lodash** or vanilla **JavaScript**.

```
const myArray = [
    {
        id:1,
        category:"HappyBirthday",
        title:"Best wishes"
    },      
    {
        id:2,
        category:"HappyBirthday",
        title:"Happy Birthday"
    },      
    {
        id:3,
        category:"TopPerformer",
        title:"Good job - Girl"
    },
    {
        id:4,
        category:"TopPerformer",
        title:"Wish you continued success"
    },
    {
        id:5,
        category:"WorkAnniversary",
        title:"Happy work anniversary"
    }
];
```

**Expected Result :**

```
const searchResults = [
    {
        id:1,
        category:"HappyBirthday",
        title:"Best wishes"
    },                  
    {
        id:4,
        category:"TopPerformer",
        title:"Wish you continued success"
    }           
];
```

Comment: Have you tried with [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)?

Comment: `myArray.filter(item => item.title.toLowerCase().includes('wish'))`

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca: No, filter not tried.

Answer (score 3):

```js
const myArray = [
    {
        id:1,
        category:"HappyBirthday",
        title:"Best wishes"
    },      
    {
        id:2,
        category:"HappyBirthday",
        title:"Happy Birthday"
    },      
    {
        id:3,
        category:"TopPerformer",
        title:"Good job - Girl"
    },
    {
        id:4,
        category:"TopPerformer",
        title:"Wish you continued success"
    },
    {
        id:5,
        category:"WorkAnniversary",
        title:"Happy work anniversary"
    }
];

const filtered = myArray.filter(obj => obj.title.toLowerCase().includes("wish"));

console.log(filtered);
```

Or you could simply do this:

```
myArray.filter(item => item.title.match(/wish/i));
```

Here I am using Regular Expression and checking if the title contains the word `wish`. The `i` there tells the engine to ignore case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions for this.

```
const retval = myArray.filter(x => x.title.match(/wish/i));
```

**Important**

It is really important to include this if you want to skip case sensitivity in your filter

```
/i
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple `Array.prototype.filter` with `RegExp.prototype.test` should do the job:

```
const myArray=[{id:1,category:"HappyBirthday",title:"Best wishes"},{id:2,category:"HappyBirthday",title:"Happy Birthday"},{id:3,category:"TopPerformer",title:"Good job - Girl"},{id:4,category:"TopPerformer",title:"Wish you continued success"},{id:5,category:"WorkAnniversary",title:"Happy work anniversary"}]

const filtered = myArray.filter(({title}) => /wish/gi.test(title));

console.log(filtered);
```